# /mnt folder missing docker toolbox

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

I am attempting to copy a folder from my local directory to a docker container. I hear that for Docker Toolbox copying works a bit differently and that instead of being copied directly the folder should be mounted in a folder /mnt. This folder seems to be missing for me:

$ ls /

bin/  cmd/  dev/  etc/  git-bash.exe*  git-cmd.exe*  LICENSE.txt  mingw64/  proc/  ReleaseNotes.html  tmp/  unins000.dat  unins000.exe*  unins000.msg  usr/

If it helps, the /tmp folder in the docker terminal is the same one as the local folder which is a but strange.

To who ever can help me and finally get rid of the "copying between containers is not supported" error I keep getting, thank you.

Comment: For future note, it's generally preferred that you copy-and-paste text rather than create screenshots -- text is searchable, uses less bandwidth, and others can copy-and-paste it into programs that operate on it directly; most of the reasoning behind [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122) applies to snippets of terminal content as well as code.

Comment: Maybe you could use `scp` to copy from your host to your docker instance?

Comment: @moilejter, I tried doing that but it seems scp is not a docker command.